# How to query using fields of subclasses for Spring data repository

Tags: spring-data

Here is my entity class:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    UserIdentifier userIdentifier;
    String name;
}

public class UserIdentifier {

    String ssn;
    String id;
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UserIdentifier>
{
    User findBySsn(String ssn);
}
```

I get an exception message (runtime) saying:

```
No property ssn found on User!
```

How can I implement/declare such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Spring Data Repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) reference:

> Property expressions can refer only to a direct property of the managed entity, as shown in the preceding example. At query creation time you already make sure that the parsed property is a property of the managed domain class. However, you can also define constraints by traversing nested properties.

So, instead of

```
User findBySsn(String ssn);
```

the following worked (in my example):

```
User findByUserIdentifierSsn(String ssn);
```